# How to make Textbox control to behave as normal textbox and also behave like datetime picker

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datetime

I have a textbox control on the .ascx page. There is a setting on another pop-up page which lets the user select the date as a selection. When Date is selected in that popup then on another page which is a textbox.ascx page where there is a textbox control, datetime picker needs to showup, but when another non-date selection is made then regular textbox needs to show up.
How can I do that in JQuery or Javascript. As of now I have textbox field like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="pre" runat="server">@</span>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Label" CssClass="textbox-label lr-question-preview"></asp:Label>
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="post" runat="server">@</span>
            </div>
```

How do I make sure that it gets updated to datetime picker on the date selection only. Can someone provide me a code sample to look at.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would place both controls (textbox  and  datepicker) and I would show or hide each one when needed (depending on selection)

Comment: I cannot. As per the requirement only one textbox needs to behave like both textbox and datetime picker.

Comment: so... you could invoke 'datepicker' widget from jQueryUI as [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) after date selection